# How would I translate "Lead the way" or "Pathfinder", "Leadership"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

This is for a tattoo, so I want the meaning to be accurate. My friend who passed was an Aiborne Ranger and they had the motto of "Lead the Way" as they were the first into battle.

It will be next to "Carpe Omnia" (seize everything)

Answer (score 1):

There is imperative (a command): "duce" (singular); "ducite" (plural) = lead!

alternatively; "abduce"/ "abducite" = "lead away!"; "induce"/ "inducite" = "lead on!"; "adduce"/ "adducite" = "lead off!".

Please read the comments from cnread. Both versions are correct, just a question of time-frames. Interesting to note that, in Latin, "duc" also means "leader" or "general"; the source of English, "Duke". Sadly, to English ears, it may sound silly being pronounced "duck", as in "bird". By sound, "Hello duck," may not be the effect a military man, or anybody, would want to create?

Comment: The singular imperative of ducere (like dicere, facere, and ferre) has no e at the end.

Comment: @cnread: I did check that: "duc" & "duce" are both given (Wiki).

Comment: Sure, but did your source say anything about the usage of each form? According to both the Gildersleeve & Lodge and Allen & Greenough grammars, the forms with *e* occur only in early Latin, and even there the forms without seem to be more common (Sihler, *New comparative grammar of Greek and Latin* 73.1 describes the forms with *e* as 'scantily-attested'). If you're deliberately going for an attempt at an Early Latin translation, I recommend making that clear in your answer.

Comment: @cnread: Thank you. Added an edit. Happy Christmas.